# HTML Form Action URL - add JS variable to URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, concatenation

I have a JS variable which holds the value of a PHP variable.

```
<script>
var xxxx = "<?= $v2 ?>";
</script>
```

I also have a form which points to superman.php

```
<form action="superman.php" method="get" target="_blank">
```

I need to amend superman.php so that it holds:

1. values from elements in the form
2. **and the javascript variable too**

How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can append hidden input:

```
addDataToForm('xxxx', xxxx);

function addDataToForm(name, value){
  var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
  var hidden = document.createElement('input');
  hidden.type = 'hidden';
  hidden.name = name;
  hidden.value = value;
  form.appendChild(hidden);
}
```

Comment: Where do I paste this? addDataToForm('xxxx', xxxx);  Which one of the xxxx is my variable?

Comment: in script tag. addDataToForm('name', 'val'); is same as writing action of form like this: <form action="superman.php?name=val" method="get" target="_blank">